# Handling buttons in textview iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, textview

I am displaying a information in the textview which consists of phone numbers and mail_id on clicking on the numbers the users should be able to dial to the contact, for that i have added a button in that particular place.

When the users scrolls the button is not scrolling only the text is scrolling.

So i have called the Textview & ScrollView Delegate  and got the offset value of the scroll View. so that i can set buttons frame .

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView){
    let rol_y = aboutTextView.contentOffset.y;
    let rol_x = aboutTextView.contentOffset.x;

    print("\(rol_x),\(rol_y)")

}
```

After getting the offset value, how can i set the frame..?

Is this method works..?

Or

How can i do this ...?

Comment: are you displayed HTML content ?

Comment: No the data is static

Comment: then why you are used separate button ?

Comment: text contains a phone number in the middle .when the user taps that he should be able to call. In order for that i used a button at that particular place.

Comment: why are you showing the text view for display the two static data you can use label and button instead of text view and give the action on that button.

Comment: the data consists of about 40 lines and need to scrolled

Comment: Just select the UITextView in your storyboard and go to "Show Attributes inspector" and select phone numbers and links in detection .

Comment: @KKRocks  after selecting the Numbers and links in the detection the user will be able to call also...?

Comment: Yes use can call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just select the UITextView in your storyboard and go to "Show Attributes inspector" and select phone numbers and links in Data Detectors.

[image]